# LEFT JOIN or REGULAR JOIN, and how to compare MySql table to an array? Need performance!

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I have six tables: t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6. And I also have one main table: main_table. TOTAL 7 TABLES!

Now, I am using SOLR for the searching of classifieds, and the results from solr are put into an array. The array results are ID:nrs which I use to match agains the same ID:s in MySql.

The first column of ALL tables in MySql is called classified_id.

If the user searches for "cars", then Solr will find all cars classifieds, put the id:s into an array and finally compare the MySql main table to match everything in table t1 (which is the cars table) where classified_id is the same in both tables.

The SOLR results array is first imploded, then:

```
SELECT * FROM classified, t1 WHERE classified.ad_id IN ('$solr_id_arr_imploded') AND classified.classified_id=t1.classified_id
```

My Q is, is this how I should do this? Is this how I should JOIN here, or use a LEFT JOIN? Is there any faster way of comparing to the array?

the table `t1` may be empty if there are no car-classifieds...

Remember, the query could become **very very** long, for example if SOLR returns 10000 matches, then an array of 10000 id numbers which look like this would be returned: `bmw_m3_low_miles_8948939`

Thanks

Comment: Will the results of the search be paged? That is, if the SOLR search returns those 10,000 matches, do you need to fetch them all at once, or just (e.g.) 50 at a time?

Comment: Hi. The results are paged with MySql LIMIT. Not Solr. However if you know of how to do this in Solr, maybe this is how to go then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to `IN` is to create a temporary table, fill it with the IDs, and perform an inner join on that. Make sure the other tables have an index on `classified_id`. To compare the options, [use `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html).